# WPF usercontrol property change doesn't trigger event?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I have wrote a **Usercontrol** for my wpf project. It's a *IPAddress* control which contains four **TextBox** like this:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox  Grid.Column="0"  x:Name="txtboxFirstPart" TextChanged="txtbox_TextChanged" MaxLength="3" BorderThickness="0" TabIndex="1" PreviewKeyDown="txtboxFirstPart_PreviewKeyDown" PreviewKeyUp="txtboxFirstPart_PreviewKeyUp" Width="31" />
    <Label Content="." Grid.Column="1"   x:Name="label1" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" x:Name="txtboxSecondPart" MaxLength="3" TextChanged="txtbox_TextChanged" BorderThickness="0" TabIndex="2" KeyDown="txtboxSecondPart_KeyDown" PreviewKeyUp="txtboxSecondPart_PreviewKeyUp" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="31"/>
    <Label Content="." Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="label2" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White" />
    <TextBox  Grid.Column="4" x:Name="txtboxThridPart" MaxLength="3" TextChanged="txtbox_TextChanged" BorderThickness="0" TabIndex="3" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"  KeyDown="txtboxThridPart_KeyDown" PreviewKeyUp="txtboxThridPart_PreviewKeyUp" Width="31" />
    <Label Content="." Grid.Column="5" x:Name="label3" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White" />
    <TextBox  Grid.Column="6" x:Name="txtboxFourthPart" MaxLength="3" TextChanged="txtbox_TextChanged" BorderThickness="0" TabIndex="4" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="31" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

And I append **Text** property to it:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(IPAddressControl),
                                                             new PropertyMetadata("0.0.0.0", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextPropertyChanged)));
private static void OnTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    IPAddressControl o = d as IPAddressControl;
    try
    {
        var value = e.NewValue as string;
        var splitValues = new string[4];
        if (value != null)
        {
            var splits = value.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            Array.Copy(splits, splitValues, splits.Length);
        }
        o.txtboxFirstPart.Text = splitValues[0];
        o.txtboxSecondPart.Text = splitValues[1];
        o.txtboxThridPart.Text = splitValues[2];
        o.txtboxFourthPart.Text = splitValues[3];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error in IP control see inner exception!", ex);
    }
    o.RaiseTextChanged(e);
}

public string Text
{
    get { return (string)this.GetValue(IPAddressControl.TextProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(IPAddressControl.TextProperty, value); }
}

public event DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler TextChanged;
protected virtual void RaiseTextChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.TextChanged != null)
    {
        this.TextChanged(this, e);
    }
}
```

When I use it in my project with databinding like this:

```
<GroupBox Name="gb_Tcp" DataContext="{Binding TcpCollection}">
   <my:IPAddressControl Text="{Binding IpAddress}" />   
</GroupBox>
```

I succeed read the **IpAddress** from binding source. Now I changed the value of this user-control, and in a button_click event I try to reset the value of this user-control to default like this:

```
private void btn_IpReset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tb_IpAddress.Text = "...";
}
```

I found that the **tb_IpAddress.Text** value is the default value, but the **txtboxFirstPart**(one textbox of the user-control I changed) keeps the old value. Which indicate that the **DepedencyProperty** OnTextPropertyChanged didn't triggered.

So How should I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to adhere to dependency property naming conventions. If the property is named `MyText`, the identifier field must be `MyTextProperty`. Besides that, make sure you do not explicitly set the DataContext of the UserControl, like `DataContext = this` in its constructor. That's ok for a MainWindow, but not for a UserControl. As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the Binding is pointless, because it is the default behavior. You may also set `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault` on registration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I try to set`(IPAddressControl)tb_IpAddress.GetBindingExpression(myTextProperty).UpdateSource();` the compiler errors : "no DependencyProperty 'myTextProperty' found."

Comment: If `tb_IpAddress` is an IPAddressControl, you don't need the cast. `tb_IpAddress.GetBindingExpression(IPAddressControl.myTextProperty)` should work. And please note that there are widely accepted naming conventions for class and public member names in C#. Use `MyText` and `MyTextProperty`.

Comment: I found that I defined the **DependencyProperty** as TextProperty. So after change it to `tb_IpAddress.GetBindingExpression(IPAddressControl.TextProperty).UpdateSource();` passed the compiler. But still not change the text. Debugging found: **myText** is the new value, but **txtboxFirstPart** still keeps the old value.

Comment: @BarryLib, there are some areas of code that are missing, which are crucial to understanding your problem: what is your datacontext, and if it is set or not.

Comment: datacontext is a collection of default value for these user-control which read from xml. I update the code though I don't think it's related.

Comment: I didn't set the DataContext for the User-Control.

Comment: And for the `GetBindingExpression(IPAddressControl.TextProperty)` from one of your previous comments. **Once again:** The identifier field of a dependency property named `XYZ` **must** be named `XYZProperty` and nothing else. The combination `myText` and `TextProperty` **does not work**. Please try to keep that in mind.

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502939/user-controls-dependency-property-not-binding) very related.